# selecting the specific element of the same class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some paragraph(in h3 tag) like this

```
<h3 id="para1" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>

<h3 id="para2" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>

<h3 id="para3" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>
```

They all have the same class para I want to choose a specific para like para2 not using its id but class
how can I do that?

if I didn't explain it correctly, I just wanna know how can I select a specific element of same class. what type of selector should I use because it's difficult to work with id.

Comment: *because it's difficult to work with id.* --> it will be more difficult with another selector. ID is the most suitable selector to select a specific element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest selecting your element with the `id` selector since that is the unique identifier for this element. But you could use the `:nth-child()` selector if you know how much elements of the class there are and which child you want to select. For instance below example selects the second child:

```css
h3.para:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="para1" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>

<h3 id="para2" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>

<h3 id="para3" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>
```

Comment: @Terminator-Darbapapa Thanks a lot for your answer, the mistake I was making was that I was using the `class=" para" ` only not the tag name `<h3>`

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to the element using both its class and id:

```
.para#para2 {
  ...
}
```

And if you prefer dealing only with classes, then you can do this:

```
<h3 class="para para1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
</h3>

<h3 class="para para2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
</h3>

<h3 class="para para3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
</h3>
```

And then refer to the element using both classes:

```
.para.para2 {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, simply use `:not() with nth-child()`.

```css
h3.para:not(:nth-child(2)) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="para1" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>

<h3 id="para2" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>

<h3 id="para3" class="para">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
      </h3>
```

Comment: What's the output you expect?

Comment: OP specifically asked not to use the `id` selector. Also this targets everything but the required element.

Comment: I updated my answer please check again.

Comment: @RiyasAc it was fully opposite to what I wanted thnx for your reply though. learned something new